# Convert Mysql Query to SQL query with function SUM() and Group by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have MySql Query so i want to convert into MS SQL server query.
when i trying to convert then error occur :
ColumnName is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I Have Already tried but cannot show silimar output as Mysql Query

```
//Mysql Query Execute Proparly:
select lm.*,fm.Fund_Name from (select max(id) Id,Office_Id,max(Fund_Key) 
Fund_Key, Return_Month,Tax_Payer_GST,Tax_Payer,
Tax_Payer_asPer_GST, SUM(User_Tot_Gross) 
User_Tot_Gross,SUM(System_Tot_Gross) System_Tot_Gross,
SUM(IGST) IGST, SUM(CGST) CGST,SUM(SGST) SGST,SUM(TAX_Payble) 
TAX_Payble,SubmittedStatus 
from ledger_master WHERE STATUS='Active' group by 
Return_Month,Tax_Payer_GST,Office_Id,Tax_Payer,Tax_Payer_asPer_GST, 
SubmittedStatus)
lm left join office_master om on lm.Office_Id=om.Id 
left join fund_master fm on lm.Fund_Key=fm.Fund_Key  
WHERE om.GSTNo='27ABCPD1234E1Z1'

//SQL Server Query execute but not showing result properly :
SELECT lm.Id,lm.Office_Id,lm.Fund_Key,lm.Return_Month,lm.Tax_Payer_GST,
lm.Tax_Payer, 
lm.Tax_Payer_asPer_GST,SUM(lm.User_Tot_Gross) User_Tot_Gross,
SUM(lm.System_Tot_Gross) System_Tot_Gross,SUM(lm.IGST) IGST,
SUM(lm.CGST) CGST,SUM(lm.SGST) SGST,SUM(lm.TAX_Payble) TAX_Payble,
fm.Fund_Name,lm.SubmittedStatus 
FROM ledger_master AS lm  INNER JOIN fund_master AS fm ON 
fm.Fund_Key=lm.Fund_Key  
INNER JOIN office_master AS om ON om.Id=lm.Office_Id  
WHERE lm.Status='Active' AND om.GSTNo='27ABCPD1234E1Z1' 
GROUP BY lm.tax_Payer_GST,lm.Fund_Key,lm.Return_Month,lm.SubmittedStatus
```

Comment: You mention one query that you want to convert, but your question has two queries.  I'm confused.

Comment: Run one query at a time and check which query thorws an error!

Comment: first query in mySql and second one SQL

Comment: 1st query execute proparly but second one cannot show result as mysql query,

Comment: *but not showing result properly* ... is not helpful for us. No records? Too few or too many? Wrong groupings? Please show us why query returns undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think *ALL* of your non-aggregate fields in the select (lm.id, lm.office_id, ... I count nine of them) have to be in the group by clause. So far, your group by only contains four of those.

Thus, your might want to try:

```
//SQL Server Query execute but not showing result properly :
SELECT lm.Id,lm.Office_Id,lm.Fund_Key,lm.Return_Month,lm.Tax_Payer_GST,
lm.Tax_Payer, 
lm.Tax_Payer_asPer_GST,SUM(lm.User_Tot_Gross) User_Tot_Gross,
SUM(lm.System_Tot_Gross) System_Tot_Gross,SUM(lm.IGST) IGST,
SUM(lm.CGST) CGST,SUM(lm.SGST) SGST,SUM(lm.TAX_Payble) TAX_Payble,
fm.Fund_Name,lm.SubmittedStatus 
FROM ledger_master AS lm  INNER JOIN fund_master AS fm ON 
fm.Fund_Key=lm.Fund_Key  
INNER JOIN office_master AS om ON om.Id=lm.Office_Id  
WHERE lm.Status='Active' AND om.GSTNo='27ABCPD1234E1Z1' 
GROUP BY lm.tax_Payer_GST,lm.Fund_Key,lm.Return_Month,lm.SubmittedStatus,fm.fund_name,lm.id,lm.office_id,lm.tax_payer,lm.tax_payer_asper_gst
```

Comment: Thank your @Oceansunfish  for your response but i want to without group by on lm.Tax_Payer, 
lm.Tax_Payer_asPer_GST but show in  result. this was unique field in table so, what i do

Answer (score 0):

This error is in your second query, and something that older versions on MySQL allow you to get away with, but newer versions and other RDBMSs (like SQL Server) will not allow.

The issue is that you have a GROUP BY statement that will aggregate all of your results so that there is one line per group, but you have fields in your SELECT clause that are not either enclosed in aggregate functions or part of the GROUP BY clause. The problem is that, if a field meets neither of these conditions, SQL cannot determine which value you want to return for that field, because there are several possibilities - one for each member of the group.

Your version of MySQL just picks the first value it comes across to resolve this issue, which is bad because it could theoretically be different between different executions of your query if say the order of rows changes in the database.

To explain the error message a bit further:

- If the field is **part of the GROUP BY statement** it is fine, because
  the groups are identified by each unique value of the field, so SQL never has to pick a value.
- If the field is **enclosed in an aggregate function**, like SUM in your
  example, all of the possible values are reduced down to one value
  deterministically - in the case of SUM, they are all added together.

To solve this issue, first take a look at which fields in your query do not meet these conditions. It looks to me like that includes the following fields:

```
lm.Id,
lm.Office_Id,
lm.Tax_Payer, 
lm.Tax_Payer_asPer_GST,
fm.Fund_Name
```

You've got three possible solutions for each of these fields:

- Add the field to the GROUP BY clause. This might be the appropriate thing to do, but likely it is not because it will split your current groups into smaller groups by the different possible values of the field.
- Enclose each of those fields with an aggregate function. If you really don't care which out of the possible values gets returned, you can use either `MIN` or `MAX` around each field to pick the first or last deterministically. Or, find a more appropriate aggregate function to pick the values that you want.
- Remove the field from the query if you don't really need it there.

Comment: Thank your @RobStreeting for your response in that need all field but without group by lm.Id,
lm.Office_Id,
lm.Tax_Payer, 
lm.Tax_Payer_asPer_GST, this column when simply putting the column name the  error ocur ColumnName is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. then i was use in that aggregate function.